# induced maximal ideals in ring of functions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $X$ be a non-empty set. 
We know that $\operatorname{Map}(X,R) = \{f : X \to R\}$ is a ring 
where,   $(f+g)(x)= f(x) + g(x)$   and $(f\cdot g)(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)$ 

I want to know that if $M$ is a maximal ideal in $R$ whether this ideal induces a maximal ideal in $\operatorname{Map}(X,R)$?

Answer (score 1):

Not only one, but sometimes *many.*  For each $x\in X$ and maximal ideal $M$, you can consider the subset of functions $f$ such that $f(x)\in M$.  If you check, you'll find this is a maximal ideal of the set of functions.

It is not always the case that these are *all* the maximal ideals, though.